# MYSQL auto fill column values from another table

Tags: mysql, database

im very new to databases :) now with that said.

I have a table **(sellers)** with the columns: *Seller_id, Seller_logo*. There are 5 sellers.
I have a table **(details)** with the columns : *Details_id, Seller_logo, Product, Price*. There are 1000 Products.

Today i decided to insert a new column at the **(sellers)** table, with name *"seller_name"* and i fill in the values very easy since there are just 5 sellers.

**The problem :** How can i add in the **(Details)** table, a new column *"seller_name"* and automatic fill the values of the from the **(sellers)** table?

*i created a relation between *Seller_logo* on the tables **(Sellers and Details)**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't do that... you will be storing seller information in details table where it does not belong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relationship should be by Seller_id and I suppose the details table is for products? I would recommend this structure and then when you query the `details` table you would ideally use MySQL Join Syntax http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html to get the related `seller_name`

```
**Sellers**
1. Seller_id
2. Seller_name
3. Seller_logo

**Details**
1. Details_id
2. Seller_id (foreign key)
3. Product
4. Price
```